# Нескромный вопрос (в продолжение Ёшкиного Кота)

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Мы выяснили, что Ёшкин Кот изначально не был заменой матерного слова, хотя потом стал ассоциироваться с ним. Однако есть целый "куст" эвфемизмов-междометий, которые восходят именно ко всем известному глаголу. Например, "ё-моё", "ёпрст", "ёклмн" и даже "яп-онский городовой". Видимо, есть масса других вариантов.

Но! Они все начинаются на букву "ё" (и даже "я"). А ведь в исходном глаголе, насколько я знаю, на первом месте стоит "е", а не "ё". Почему так? Потому что гласные "о", "а" более экспрессивны, чем "э"? Или само исходное слово раньше звучало по-другому?

Да и вариант в виде причастия/отглагольного прилагательного тоже начинается в "ё".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ё, конечно, гораздо более экспрессивно. Оно всегда ударное. :)
Вопроса я, признаться до конца не понял. Все что могу пока сказать, Переход Е<О в начальной позиции (иногда и в середине слова после йота) - историческая закономерность, А Е  и Я (фактически О и А) часто путались в русском вне какой-то фонетическо-исторической причины. История с Ягой, которая оказалась Ёжкой - тому подтверждение.
Так что какой-то особой подоплеки я тут не вижу.
Если Вы, конечно, об этом...

Answer (score 2):

Материться не хочу на уважаемом сайте, просто отсылаю Вас к словарю русских синонимов. http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-19275.htm
Добавлю, что Е меняется на Я или Ё в зависимости от сложившихся в очень старые времена местных предпочтений. http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-19295.htm   Это теперь все перемешалось. А в сербском и болгарском "ябати" - совсем не табуированное слово.В такой же форме и таким же значением оно имеется в санскрите откуда и унаследовано нами тысячи лет назад.

Comment: Значит, местные предпочтения. Ладно. 

Умилил синоним насчет гипотенузы :-)). Кстати, во многих "заменителях" вообще минимально звуковое соответствие, скорее копируется синтаксическая структура (действие+объект)